# pointer being realloc'd was not allocated char**

Tags: c, malloc, memory-management, realloc

Здравствуйте, 
Если просто компилирую и запускаю этот код, то всё хорошо работает, но если пытаюсь запустить этот код в режиме debug, сразу же вылетает эта ошибка. Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема. Заранее спасибо.

```
//Parse file
Chapter readFile(FILE *file)
{
    int takeMemory = 0;
    int reallocateCounter = 1;
    int charPosition = 0;
    char letter;
    int newLineCounter = 0;
    // Get memory for input text
    char** fileText = NULL;
    fileText = (char**) malloc(FILE_LINE_NUMBERS * sizeof(char*));
    if(fileText == NULL)
    {
        free(fileText);
        errorHandling(2);
        exit(2);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < FILE_LINE_NUMBERS; i++)
    {
        fileText[i] = (char*) calloc(ARGUMENT_SIZE, sizeof(char));
        checkMemoryCorruption(fileText[i]);
    }
    //Read file
    do
    {
        if(newLineCounter > 3 && takeMemory)
        {
            takeMemory = 0;
            char** temp_arr = (char**) realloc(fileText, (newLineCounter+1)
                                                         * sizeof(char*));
            if(temp_arr == NULL)
            {
                free(temp_arr);
                errorHandling(2);
                exit(2);
            }
            fileText[newLineCounter] = (char*) calloc(ARGUMENT_SIZE, sizeof(char));
            checkMemoryCorruption(fileText[newLineCounter]);
        }
        letter = (char) fgetc(file);
        if(letter == '\n')
        {
            takeMemory++;
            newLineCounter++;
            charPosition = 0;
            reallocateCounter = 1;
            continue;
        }
        if(charPosition > ARGUMENT_SIZE * reallocateCounter - 2)
        {
            fileText[newLineCounter] = realloc(fileText[newLineCounter],
                                               (size_t )ARGUMENT_SIZE
                                               * reallocateCounter);
            checkMemoryCorruption(fileText[newLineCounter]);
        }
        fileText[newLineCounter][charPosition] = letter;
        charPosition++;
    }
    while(letter != EOF);
    fclose(file);
    for(int i = 0; i < newLineCounter + 1; i++)
        free(fileText[i]);

    free(fileText);
    Chapter retur;
    return retur;
}
```